# ajax success function not working on datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using datatable to show list from database mysql

I need to update some input on end of table loading, then I'm using success function but this seems to prevent data rendering

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
'processing': true,
'serverSide': true,
'ajax': {
  type: 'POST',
  'url': url,
  'data': function (d) {
    console.log(d.order);
    return JSON.stringify( d );
  },

  // EDIT this "my" success function
  success: function( data ) {
    $('#my_input').val(data.return);
  }
}
```

Json returned is:

```
{
 "data":[[ (datatable value) ]],
 "returned":"myvalue"
}
```

here the jsfiddle

EDIT
http://jsfiddle.net/ntcwust8/95/

Comment: Just remove success callback

Comment: what is data.return in your success callback . As i can see there is no such field in json return from this link 
http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cbEfqLwFaq?indent=2

Comment: my json have a data.returned... Or anyway I need to update an input after table is loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove success callback.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'ajax': {
          type: 'POST',
          'url': url,
          'data': function (d) {
            console.log(d.order);
            return JSON.stringify( d );
          }
        }
```

**Edit**

you need to use ajax.dataSrc property it will call after ajax finish.
It will work on refresh as well
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'ajax': {
      type: 'POST',
      'url': url,
      'data': function (d) {
        console.log(d.order);
        return JSON.stringify( d );
      },
      "dataSrc": function (json) {
       $("#mydata").val(json.recordsTotal);
       return json.data;
        }
    },

  });
```

here is updated fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/2jkg3kqo/2/

Comment: Sorry for my english, but I need to update an input value with data returned from json... View my EDIT success function

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `success` callback.

> success - Must not be overridden as it is used internally in
>   DataTables. To manipulate / transform the data returned by the server
>   use ajax.dataSrc (above), or use ajax as a function

[Datatable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) by default handles the `success` callback, Don't override it.

Instead use `complete` option of `AJAX` to do something after data loading.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arajajyothibabu/ntcwust8/96/)

Comment: Sorry for my english, but I need to update an input value with data returned from json... View my EDIT success function

Comment: Yes you can use the response to do whatever you want. check the updated fiddle here

Comment: `Complete` works every time whenever ajax is called.

Answer (score 4):

Datatable has its own `complete` event thats called `initComplete`.

If you redefine `success` you are overriding Datatable's own function.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': {
    ....
    ....
    },    
   'initComplete':function(settings, json){
        alert($('#example tbody tr').length+ ' records on screen');
 });
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete

Update fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/ntcwust8/94/

Comment: Sorry for my english, but I need to update an input value on every reload with data returned from json... View my EDIT success function

Comment: @FireFoxII the `initComplete` function gets a `json` variable that's an object with the data from the ajax call. You can access it like `json.data`, thats an array to all the data.

Comment: yes but seems not working when I call table.ajax.reload();

Comment: @FireFoxII when you do `ajax.reload` the `Processing...` text never hides , so, I think there is an error somewhere else.